# Farm configuration failed during step 3 = sqlexception error + infinite "not running in high constrat ..." messages

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql-server

I try to install a farm with the following requirments :

- windows server 2012 r2 + sql server 2012 sp2
- windows server 2012 r2 + sharepoint 2013

SQL Server was correctly configured (`alias, autogrowth, paralelism, dbcreator/securityadmin for farm configuration account, etc.`)

Servers are on the same VMWare ESX, same LUN, same virtual network (no problem to contact SQL Server through the SharePoint Server)

The farm configuration wizard failed on step 3, AdminContent and Config databases are slowly configured and populated during this process (can take 1 hour before crash).
During this time, PSDiagnostics logs was spam with this message "

> Not running in high constrat, so we will paint the background with our
>   trademark image" (size of log = 30 Ko). Event log show a 3355 error
>   (timeout sqlexception)

Microsoft support advises me to uninstall SQL Server 2012 SP2 and try SQL Server 2012 SP1.
Is anyone have ever experienced this problem?

Comment: can you share the PSDiag Log, the error msg is very much generic.

Comment: hello @WaqasSarwarMCSE you can see the log here : http://bit.ly/1EXwSKS (i cut 30 minutes of "not running ...").MS support find the "SharePoint 2010" reference very strange (even if the version was 15.xxxx)

Comment: Log pointing towards the SQL Server....SharePoint trying to connect to SQL but timedout...may be bad network between SQL and SP server, Bad Configuration at SQL level, May be any firewall rule causing this or any Security software blocking this.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE antivirus is off. firewall is off. same virtual network. i try using sql server 2012 sp1 instead of sp2 but problem is the same. this is very weird...